# Is there a way to use an array in HTML?

Tags: random, stylesheet

I want my html to start with a random css file with an Array. Is this possible?

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='CSS/katy.css'>


var cssName1= [ 'CSS/katy.css', 'CSS/daftpunk.css', 'CSS/wiliam.css'];
var rndIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var rndCss = cssName1[rndIndex];
```

Like putting in href="rndCss"?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply stylesheet dynamically with jQuery like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cssName1= [ 'CSS/katy.css', 'CSS/daftpunk.css', 'CSS/wiliam.css'];
    var rndIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    var rndCss = cssName1[rndIndex];
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + rndCss + '" type="text/css" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way but you can definitely use javascript to do such funky things.